# как обрезать строку до пробела в Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пример :

```
"11A 2",
"22A"
```

т.е. должно получится
"11A" и "22A"

Я использую

```
substring( поле from 1 for position(' 'in поле)) ss
```

Вроде как отрабатывает для первого случая, т.е. когда есть пробел, но во втором (его нет) ничего не выводится.
Может как по другому можно записать?

Answer (score 3):

[split_part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) обладает нужным поведением:

```
melkij=> select split_part('11A 2', ' ', 1);
 split_part 
------------
 11A
(1 строка)

melkij=> select split_part('22A', ' ', 1);
 split_part 
------------
 22A
(1 строка)
```